# XSLT 1.0: How to retrieve a text substring from a preceding node that matches certain conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to implement a stylesheet to be used by an XSLT 1.0 processor, but can't figure out how to retrieve a text substring from a preceding node that matches certain conditions. The conditions are described in the XSL stylesheet snippet further below, but first here's an example of the input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataRoot>
   <dataRow>
      <a0>Blank 25/10/2013</a0>
   </dataRow>
   <dataRow>
      <a0>2013006430</a0>
      <a5>31.84</a5>
   </dataRow>
   <dataRow>
      <a0>Blank 24/10/2013</a0>
   </dataRow>
   <dataRow>
      <a0>2013006409</a0>
      <a5>0.5504</a5>
   </dataRow>
   <dataRow>
      <a0>2013006410</a0>
      <a5>7.376</a5>
   </dataRow>
</dataRoot>
```

...and here's the XSL stylesheet, in which I need to figure out how to get the 'dateAnalysed' value as described inline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <INBOUND>
            <xsl:for-each select="dataRoot/dataRow">

                <xsl:variable name="dateAnalysed">
                    <!-- How can I implement the following as an xpath expression? -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="text following 'Blank ' in the last preceding a0 node with text that starts with 'Blank '"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="sampleId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="a0"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Do stuff with $dateAnalysed and $sampleId -->
            </xsl:for-each>
        </INBOUND>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To give a bit more context here's what the output should look like:

```
<INBOUND>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006430</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>A5</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>31.84</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006430</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>Date</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>25/10/2013</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006409</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>A5</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>0.5504</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006409</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>Date</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>24/10/2013</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006410</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>A5</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>7.376</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
  <INBOX_SAMPLE>
    <SAMPLE_ID>2013006410</SAMPLE_ID>
    <PARAMETER_NAME>Date</PARAMETER_NAME>
    <SRESULT>24/10/2013</SRESULT>
  </INBOX_SAMPLE>
</INBOUND>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I believe you're looking for this xpath:

`substring-after(preceding-sibling::dataRow[starts-with(a0,'Blank ')]/a0,'Blank ')`

To break it down, `preceding-sibling::dataRow` will find the previous dataRow element, the `[starts-with(a0,'Blank ')` will restrict that to the first that has an `a0` element with content starting with `'Blank '`. Finally the `substring-after` function is applied to the value of the `a0` element within it, and returns the remaining string after the `'Blank '`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the xpath just needed a slight tweak to have it select the most recent 'Blank ' node instead of the first: substring-after((preceding-sibling::dataRow[starts-with(a0,'Blank ')])[last()]/a0,'Blank ')

Comment: Hm.. that's a weird one. When I try it, `[1]` picks the most recent node, as that list should be in reverse order. What xsl processor are you using?